# angle level calculate, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors, sensors

Hi i'm creating a level tool on android studio and this is my code

```
// More code goes here
        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
                rotationMatrix, sensorEvent.values);

// Remap coordinate system
float[] remappedRotationMatrix = new float[16];
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
        SensorManager.AXIS_X,

        SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
        remappedRotationMatrix);

// Convert to orientations
SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedRotationMatrix, orientations);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    orientations[i] = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientations[i]));
}
DECIMAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("#.0");

TextView details = findViewById(R.id.details);

value.setText("X "+ DECIMAL_FORMATTER.format(orientations[0]) +"°\n"+ "Y "+ DECIMAL_FORMATTER.format(orientations[1])+"°\n"+ "Z "+ DECIMAL_FORMATTER.format(orientations[2])+"°");
details.setText(R.string.level_details);
```

This code print the angle on 3 axis but i want to print on one value as a real bubble level. What can i do?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? A bubble level does not "print values" (or maybe fancy modern electronic ones do?) Also, if you've found answers to your previous questions useful, don't forget to upvote them and mark them as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Bubble level give you a value, a single angolation. But with this code i have 3 angles on X, Y and Z. How can i obtain that value ?

Comment: Alright but what is that single angle? It must be an angle between two things, what are those two things?

Comment: I think between two axis. I think x and y. How can i determine it?

Comment: The angle between x and y axis is 90 degrees. You probably want the angle between one of the phone's axis and some global reference axis?

Comment: I want only realize a bubble spirit level that shows me the inclination angle about the position of the telephone so i want  to take the floor where my phone is located as a reference point

Comment: Maybe there's another way to bring clarity: In what position do you think the angle should be zero? When the phone is lying flat on a table with the screen pointing up? Or when the phone is upright with the screen pointing to your face?

Comment: When the phone is lying flat on a table with the screen pointing up

Comment: Please add any clarifications to your Question. Do not provide those only in comments.